# Is the script in style tag considered as CSS?

Tags: html, css

My professor asked us to develop a website using pure HTML, 
JUST HTML. And it's really hard to design without CSS but I have to follow her instructions.

Anyway, my question is do you consider this code as CSS even if I removed the type="text/css"?

```
 <style>
           a {color:white;  }   
 </style>
```

This maybe a dumb question but thanks for your time to answer it, I just really want to use CSS to make it easier.

Could you suggest anything that would make my coding easier? I just don't want to have repetitive code.

Comment: Yes that's CSS itself.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why has your professor asked you to do this?  Are you sure you've understood his/her request?  It seems like encouraging bad practice (using font tags, layout with tables etc..)

Comment: I suggest that you don't attempt to style the page(s) at all. Just ensure that the content is being marked up with the correct semantics.

Comment: if you really want the text in white just use <font Color="White">Link Name</font>

Comment: As Alohci suggests - Maybe the brief is to not produce something that is styled at all.  Just functionality. Default font, black text, etc.

Comment: @MrVimes I answered that inquiry below. 
My professor only wants us to used HTML coz that's the only web pl she taught us for pre-lim.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Maybe he/she wants an unstyled page then.  Just create a page that performs the function required, but isn't styled.  I guess :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having this snippet,

```
a {
   color:white;
}
```

is an element selector with the `color` property, whatever you write, i.e, between `<style>` tag, or `style` attribute, or stylesheet, all are CSS, if your professor is vintage fan, and is asking you to assign the `color` to `a` than you can use the [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) tag with `color` attribute with a value of `white`

```
<a href="#"><font color="white">Hello</font></a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UEwxH/)

> Note: Please read the box on the Mozilla Developer Network which says

[image]

**SO DON'T USE IT**

---

And just incase your professor understands, and his mind comes back to 2014... than would like to point out that even using

```
a {
   color: white;
}
```

will target all the `a` elements in your document, so make sure you use a `class` or a specific selector to select particular `a` element.

Comment: You really deserve +1

Comment: This is my second option :
  <a style="color:white" href="index.html"> HOME  </a> 
BUT I don't want to have repetitive code.
I don't have any other options, right?

Comment: Anything inside the 'style' attribute is still CSS.  Your 'color:white' here is CSS code.

Comment: @reinSano <a style="color:white" href="index.html"> HOME </a> This one is also kinda **CSS Style**, Its called **Inline CSS Style** ;)

Comment: @reinSano that's still CSS as MrVimes told you too.. but ask your professor why he needs that to be done with HTML only

Comment: @reinSano you welcome :) and do give greetings to your professor and please tell him to stop using outdated solutions

Comment: My professor only wants us to used HTML coz that's the only web pl she taught us for pre-lim. I know the other web PL though so it's really frustrating to do pure html. 

I begged her to let me use CSS but she's really decided and I don't want to have deductions for  not following her instructions.

I don't even know how to set position using HTML. -_-

Comment: @reinSano Use `table` if she wants pure HTML positioning

Answer (score 3):

> Anyway, my question is do you consider this code as CSS even if I removed the type="text/css"?

CSS is CSS, not matter how it is added to the document or labeled.

> it's really hard to design without CSS but I have to follow her instructions.
>
> Could you suggest anything that would make my coding easier?

I'd start by clarifying if CSS really is forbidden and, if it is, what the purpose of forbidding it is. I can think of a number of possible reasons:

- To prepare you to deal with code written by someone from 1996
- To make you focus on the structure and semantics instead of the appearance
- The course you are taking is almost two decades out of date

How you deal with the problem depends on which of those is the reason.

If it is the first one, then you need to look at all the obsolete, deprecated (and possibly non-standard too) presentational features of HTML (like `<font>` and `background` attributes).

If it is the second one, you just don't worry about how it looks and deal with the structure and the semantics. Let the browser's default stylesheet control the way it looks.

If it is the third one, then you probably have little option but to grit your teeth and bare it or find a better course.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
           a {color:white;  }   
 </style>
```

Yes you write `type="text/css"` or not it will be considered as css.

Answer (score 0):

The content of a `style` element is CSS, for most practical purposes (it would hardly make sense to use anything else there, since no other style sheet language is supported by browsers). The attribute `type="text/css"` does not change this, because the de facto default style sheet language is CSS.

On the other hand, the `style` element, including its content, is HTML. The content is not defined in HTML but in other specifications. Similar considerations apply to `style` attributes, as in `<a style="color: white">...</a>`: the attributes are HTML, and but they contain embedded CSS.

When you are told to use “pure HTML, JUST HTML”, then you are probably expected to refrain from using CSS or JavaScript in any way. On the other hand, you are probably allowed to use images, even though images are not HTML but are used via external references or data: URLs. There is nothing particularly logical in such a requirement.

As suggested in other answers, simply do not try to control the rendering of the page. Worry about the rendering only if it becomes intolerably messy and there is a reasonable way to prevent that in “pure HTML”. For example, don’t try to set link colors (this would in fact be an improvement over the way most web pages deal with links), backgrounds, fonts, etc. But if you use e.g. a data table, consider using , which often makes a table essentially more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

and too you can put style inline in your body or header

```
<style>
     a{
         color: #ffffff;
     }
</style>
```

and so, all your css you can write it in your native .html without use of another .css file